# Enumerate audio using assets library framework

Tags: ios, ipad, assetslibrary

I have stable code that allows me to display all user photos and I need to do same with audio files.
Is it possible to enumerate audio items like photos with asset library framework or I have to use any other library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is available using

```
MPMediaQuery * query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery]; //if you need to enumerate songs
for(MPMediaItem * item in query.items){ .... }
```